# Confusion in Java polymorphism

Tags: java

I am having confusion in java polymorphism. In dynamic method binding jvm decides at run time which class method has to call. Suppose I am having three classes A, B and C.

```
class A{
    int get(){
        return 10;
    }

    int getParent(){
        return 10;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    int get(){
        return 20;
    }
}

public class C
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        A a = new A();
        A a1 = new B();
        System.out.println(a.get());/////////////////////////LINE1    
        System.out.println(a1.get  ());////////////////////////LINE2    
        System.out.println(a.getParent());////////////////////////LINE3
    }
}
```

I am having confusion in line 1 and line3 at compile time and runtime binding.
In line 3 it a.getParent() and this method is in parent class only so what it has to decide at runtime.

In line 1 both reference and object are from same class so again what it has to decide .

Please send me any good link for runtime and compile time binding how works.

Answer (score 3):

```
    class A
    {
      public doIt( )
      {
        //this does something
      }
    }

    class B extends A
    {
      public doIt( )
      {
        //this does something
      }
    }

    class C extends B
    {
      public doIt( )
      {
        //this does something
      }

    }        

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          A x = new B( );

          x.doIt( );

    }
```

The statement that causes a lot of confusion is the “A x = new B();” statement. Although the variable x is an object of type A, it is instantiated as an object of class B – because of the “= new B( );” part of the statement. The Java runtime will basically look at this statement and say “even though x is clearly declared as type A, it is instantiated as an object of class B, so I will run the version of the doIt() method that is defined in class B.”

The version of the doIt() method that’s executed by the object x is the one in class B because of what is known as **dynamic binding** in Java – the code above can be considered to be an example of dynamic binding. Dynamic binding basically means that the method implementation that is actually called is determined at run-time, and not at compile-time. And that’s why it’s called **dynamic binding** – because the method that will be run is chosen at run time. Dynamic binding is also known as **late binding.**

In **early binding** the data and method are binds at the complie time where as in
late binding the data and method will bind at the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Class B **overrides** the get() method. So whenever you call get() on an object that is of type **B** it will use the overridden method.

Because B doesnt override getparent(), then the parent getParent() will be called when you call it on class B

Answer (score 0):

Class A provides the Object instance `a` with a virtual method table, containing A.get and A.getParent.

Class B provides the Object instance `a1` with a virtual method table, being first taken from class A, and expanded (here nothing to expand with). The `get` method is overwritten with B.get.

a1.get, even being a A, will call B.get.

Answer (score 0):

polymorphism here applies only in the case of line2. There is no concept of polymorphism applied to line1 and line3.